# How can I access the values in this array?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, firebase, rxjs

I am trying to access the value inside of an array but console keeps coming back as undefined. The array does exist and it is populated as shown by console. Issue occurs when I make reference to anything inside of the array.

```
this.comments$.subscribe({next:(value) => this.a_s.squad.push(value[0])});
```

When i console log the array

```
console.log(this.a_s.squad)
```

This is the console message
[image: Image from console.log(this.a_s.squad)]

That works fine now as we can tell the array does exist and it contains 1 object with an index of 0

**Now If I am to console log this**

```
console.log(this.a_s.squad[0])
```

It comes back as undefined
[image: Object as undefined]

This is a hindrance because I won't be able to access, sport_event_status object in the array, since if I

```
console.log(this.a_s.squad.sport_event_status)
```

I get a message stating that this does not exist on type any[]

Now if i go back to adding [0]"The index"

```
console.log(this.a_s.squad[0].sport_event_status)
```

The message error in the code no longer exist, but in the console I get this error

[image: Console Error]

Why is this happening ?

Comment: Which browser are you using?

Comment: Without seeing the code involved *all together* as it actually exists, it's hard to say what's happening. Your `console.log()` that shows the filed array and the one that attempts to get at element 0, those could be in significantly different contexts. It's impossible for anybody to know for sure however.

Comment: This is an asynchrony issue: the console is misleading you -- as you expand the array, the contents have in the mean time been populated, but that was not the case when your code tried to access element [0]. At that time the array was  still empty. We can see in your screenshot `Array []`, which means it was empty at the time the log was made.

Comment: @trincot That make much sense. How do you suggest I fix that issue, can you provide some code please?

Comment: Add a  `complete` property, like `subscribe({next: ....., complete: .....})`. That `complete` value should be a function that processes the contents that are now guaranteed to be in your array.

Comment: I did `this.comments$.subscribe({next:(value) => this.a_s.squad.push(value[0]), complete: () => this.moodArray.push(this.a_s.squad[0]) });
console.log(this.moodArray)`
So that takes care of half the issue, the code no longer breaks the app, but the array now comes back as empty and won't populate after opening in console.

Comment: You are making the same error, but now with `moodArray`. *Everything* that needs the asynchronous data, or *depends* on it (like `moodArray`) should happen in the function that you assign to `complete`, or should be *called* from there. Realise that the code in `complete` executes *later* than the `console.log(this.moodArray)` you have placed in the normal flow.

Comment: Can you please write this as an answer? Won't allow me to add `complete : () => code`

Won't allow any more than `this.moodArray.push(this.a_s.squad[0])`

Comment: Screenshots of IDEs are unfortunately not appropriate here. [Please replace images of code/logs/errors/tooltips with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: You can certainly have more than one line of code inside the complete function but you will need to use braces around it.

Comment: can anyone please just write out what I am trying to do in an answer please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is a browser feature/oddity, Below in this stack snippet you will see the problem! If you open the `chome debugger` (`F12` or `right click -> inspect element)` and check the console tab, you will notice that the even though I log the arr property twice ( arrays are stored as references to the memory location, might be related to that! ), if I open the `arr` property, it will always show the latest value instead of the snapshotted one!

So my point is, you are seeing the latest value instead of what value is present when the actual console.log was done, that is why in your screenshot you see the top says `Array[]` which means its empty! But you see values when you expand it!

[image]

```js
const arr = [1,2,3]
console.log('arr', arr);
console.log('arr[0]', arr[0]);
arr[0] = undefined;

console.log('arr', arr);
console.log('arr[0]', arr[0]);
```

Now that we got that clarified, lets revisit your code from angular perspective, I think you are accessing the property outside the subscribe that is what is giving you these issues, since very minimal code is provided its difficult to guess, but I think your situation will be like below

code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { of } from 'rxjs';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  comments$ = of([
    {
      sport_event_status: 'test',
    },
  ]);
  a_s: any = {
    squad: [],
  };
  name = 'Angular';

  ngOnInit() {
    this.comments$.subscribe({
      next: (value) => {
        this.a_s.squad.push(value[0]);
        console.log(this.a_s.squad[0].sport_event_status);
      },
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vwbbrf?description=An%20angular-cli%20project%20based%20on%20@angular/animations,%20@angular/common,%20@angular/compiler,%20@angular/core,%20@angular/forms,%20@angular/platform-browser,%20@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,%20@angular/router,%20core-js,%20rxjs,%20tslib%20and%20zone.js&file=src%2Fmain.ts&title=Angular%20Starter)

Comment: You have cracked this for me. So as stated, only when I interact with the array will there be any data shown ?

Comment: @almostasnecessary as long as we access the data inside the subscribe next block, we will surely get the data, because subscribe is an asyncronous operation, so it will not wait for the code outside the subscribe, it will complete on its own time!